# PHP remove dots and hyphens

Tags: php, date, time

Hello I need to remove dots and hyphens from both variables time and date.

This is my code:

```
$todaydate = date('Y-m-d') ."\n";
$time_utc=mktime(date('G'),date('i'),date('s'));
$NowisTime=date('G:i:s',$time_utc);
```

That will return something like this:

```
$todaydate = 2011-06-03
$NowisTime = 14:20:30
```

What I need to achieve is:

```
$todaydate = 20110603
    $NowisTime = 142030
```

How do I do this?

Thank you

Comment: You use `str_replace` function. I'll let you get some practice on your own so look it up at php.net and try it yourself.

Comment: Did you even check the manual? :/

Comment: [PHP: date - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just do:

```
$todaydate = date('Ymd');
$time_utc=mktime(date('G'),date('i'),date('s'));
$NowisTime=date('Gis',$time_utc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

```
$todaydate = date('Ymd');
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibility when dealing with strings you could use

```
preg_replace('/-|:/', null, $date);
```

Comment: If you're going this way. Just do a `str_replace()`. `preg_replace()` is slower.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would just use PHP's [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$dateTime= new DateTime('now');
var_dump(array(
    'currentDate' => $dateTime->format('Ymd'),
    'currentTime' => $dateTime->format('Gis'),
));
```

Comment: why do the str_replace call when its built into date?

Comment: Why the downvote? Perhaps he's using the date time in that format somewhere else in his code?

Comment: true.. just sounded doubtful from the request

Answer (score 0):

Don't type the hyphens and dots at all in your `date()` calls!